# PHP exec Works only on Command Line

Tags: php, mysql

I've been try to run a command in my php:

```
echo exec("mysql -uUSER -pPASS -e 'CREATE SCHEMA foo' ", $a, $b);
```

However it doesn't work when I run the script. Other commands such as **exec('pwd')**, **exec('ls')** work fine. But not this one to create database for instance.

I've checked my php settings and I've go in my php.ini:

```
safe_mode = Off
```

The funniest thing is if I run on the command line below the script works fine

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/my_php_script.php
```

I'm using APACHE 2, PHP 5.3.15 on Mac OS X.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a path issue; specify the canonical path to `mysql`.

Comment: Apache is not running with the same user as you, try echo exec("whoami"); : matter of rights

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie That shouldn't matter; authentication is done via `-u` and `-p` ... unless selinux is used perhaps.

Comment: Have you heard of the MySQL client extensions php is offering out-of-the-box? http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie you right. the command works fine on the command line as I've said. The exec("whoami") is "_www"

Comment: Just to verify if it is a right issue, you can do su _www and execute the same command...

Comment: Michel, don't be like that. This example was a simple one. The query I really want to run is  exec("mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS DB_ORIGIN | mysql -uUSER -pPASS DB_DEST", $a, $b);

Comment: give the path of mysqldump like /usr/bin/mysqldump

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: no error, no messages. The variables $a and $b are empty.